# Which of layout should i use?

Tags: android, layout

I'm confused. I want to show the map and on below of map show 5 buttons. I use RelativeLayout, but the program just show Product button. Why? I'm confused which layout i use (Linear,Relative,Frame or absolute )!! Please help me. and How can i correct this code?

location.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:apiKey="0cPRv243zM1_S3ydsNg8MJP9_6BfCp642jOhPvQ"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_home"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:text="@string/button_home"
        android:textColor="@color/text_home" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_product"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/product_icon"
        android:onClick="Product"
        android:text="@string/button_product"
        android:textColor="@color/text_product" />

  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use Linear Layout from my experience.

Comment: it's fix that you have to add 5 button below your map. or its dynamic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific problem: Instead of saying that the home button is to the left of the product button, you should say that the product button is to the right of the home button.  When a RelativeLayout is inflated, the layout is parsed in a linear way so if view A it positioned relative to view B, view B must come first.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_home"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon"
    android:text="@string/button_home"
    android:textColor="@color/text_home"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_product"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_home"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/product_icon"
    android:onClick="Product"
    android:text="@string/button_product"
    android:textColor="@color/text_product" />
```

Add this to the product button and delete the layout_toLeftOf from the home button.

> ```
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_home"
> ```

You can use gravity and alignment to position the home button and then have the other four buttons following it, each one positioned to the right of the one before it.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

- **LinearLayout** : LinearLayout is used when we need to arrange the 
  widgets/views in a horizontal or vertical manner. 
  The direction of arrangement can be set to horizontal or vertical, 
  by default it is being horizontal.
- **TableLayout** : If the Layout's widgets/views need to be arranged 
  in the form of rows and columns, we use this layout object. 
  This is similar to html tables. The cells can span columns. 
  The TableLayout do not display its border. We can be made to 
  shrink and stretch by setting the respective properties of the columns, 
  "TableRow" is another helper widget which should be used in conjunction 
  with the TableLayout.
- **RelativeLayout** : Here the position of each of the widgets/view is 
  in relative/dependent to each other. For example, when a layout is needed 
  such that it has a text view just to the left of an Edit Textbox, and a button 
  just below the EditText. The relation between the views are taken care in 
  one iteration, hence if view B’s position is dependent on view A’s position, 
  view A must come first in the layout.
- **FrameLayout** : This is a very simply layout which is used to hold a section 
  of the screen blank, for displaying an item or group of items at run time. All the 
  elements added in the framelayout will be added to the top left of the screen.
- **AbsoluteLayout** : When there is a need is to specify exact x and y co-ordinate 
  position of the view, then AbsoluteLayout need to be used. This layout is 
  difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thanks. I think, i use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout for my program.This is true?? but when i use LinearLayout, the program shows just map, not shows butons. Why? or when i use RelativeLayout, the program shows just Product button not shows home button. Why? I edit first post, and i write the program with LinearLayout

Comment: @PariyaDaghoghi: Try, Change `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your `<com.google.android.maps.MapView`.

Comment: do you want to like this way b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 .? next to each other and above view a map ?

Comment: @chintankhetiya: To whom you asking the question?

Comment: @chintankhetiya: Then mention the name as `@Pariya Daghoghi` in your comment... It will be helpful to identify the person whom to you asking.

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout by default places these 2 buttons together, so you can just see the latter.

And the line

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_product"
```

is wrong. `@+id` creates an id, use `@id` in such cases.

I would recommend LinearLayout for the situation. Place these buttons in it, and adjust them with some **margin**.